# google sheets: Import Data from a *.js from google drive - how?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a data file (suffix .js). These are on an FTP server. As far as I know google script on FTP can not access, I copy it when changing automatically using microsoft flow to google drive. How can I access the file / data in the file with google sheets?

Structure of the file:
`da[dx++]="20.12.18|1589;0|1255;0|1352;0"`

Thanks!

Comment: I'd take a look at them with something UltraEdit which is an ascii editor with built in FTP.  You could also download and view with notepad.

Comment: I think you could use FileZilla.  I think they have a built in editor but you could connect it to notepad or whatever other ascii editor you have.

Comment: Of course, I can manually download and edit the files. With Excel VBA I even do it by macro.

I would like to do it automatically (!) With google sheets. Always load a new file and update the data in google sheet.

Comment: `DriveApp.getFileByName('')`?

Comment: I'm sorry if I offended you, it was not my intention.  I don't volunteer here because I think I know so much but rather because I learn a lot.

Comment: @Cooper:I do not feel attacked or offended in any way.
If that came through my last message, that was not my intention. Possibly. it is up to the translation. I speak bad english and i use google translate

Comment: Trying Googling "google sheets script import from js file". The structure of your file is unfamiliar to me, but possibly there will be an idea in the search results that assists you.